# Why does this not throw a concurrent modification Exception while iterating through a list?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrentmodification

I have an ArrayList.

In one thread, I have a

`list.forEach(c->c.evaluate(q))`. (not relevant what c or q are). No synchronize block at all.

In another thread, I have

```
synchronize(list) {
  list.add(t)
}
```

I have the threads running simultaneously, and via logging, I can see that they are adding and modifying at the same time. There is no concurrent modification exception.

On the other hand, if I remove the synchronize from the second block of code, I instantly get concurrent mod errors.

Why is this happening? These two codes are in complete separate parts of code. Only one is in a synchronized block. I would expect that since the first for each is not in a synchronized block, there would also be exceptions?

Comment: you're performing a synchronized lock on the list, thus only one thread may enter that block at a time. It has _nothing_ to do with operations performed on the list itself (outside of calls to `list#wait` or `list#notify`)

Comment: If I was not clear, I apologize. Those are running in separate threads. Completely separate locations. one is in the sync block, the other is not

Comment: Does c.evaluate(q) "structurally modify" `list`? If not, then you should *not* expect it to motivate the exception.

Comment: no, but list.add(c) does? the amount of c's in the list will change. Before the add, there will be let's say 4 in the list. While it's iterating, it would become 5. Therefore the mod count would change, and an exception would occur. Unless there is actually synchronization going on between the method calls, even though only one is synchronized on the list

Comment: The only time you can get that exception is when two threads are trying to change the number of elements in the list (i.e., structurally change the list as the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) indicate).

Comment: My original point is that you are not actually performing any synchronization around the list in a thread-safe manner, merely buffering your calls. That `sychronized` block does not prevent two threads from accessing the same list, unless _both_ threads do `synchronized(list)` (or calls `list#wait`). There might be some funk in the spliterator for the underlying list

Comment: @JeffHolt not entirely true, you can get that exception with a single thread: `for (Object o : list) { list.add(o); }`

Comment: @Rogue That last comment deserves a citation (mcv example).

Comment: @Rogue, I agree with you 100%. That's why I am confused. Do you know for a fact that the spliterator is doing some something such as trying to acquire a lock on the list when iterating? I tried stepping through the code, and didn't see anything...

Comment: @JeffHolt I... I put one right in my comment? Go compile it with a non-empty list.

Comment: @EthanSolomon I can't imagine that someone would push production code with spliterator interacting with the sychronization mechanisms of JDK 1.2, but I can take a look if no one else has by tomorrow. Midnight deadlines. You should post your full code that is causing the error so others can debug it.

Comment: I think it’s likely that using `synchronized` in one of the threads changed the timing just enough that the synchronized block and the other thread’s `forEach` executed at different times.

Comment: @Rogue there are no errors. thats why I'm shocked

Comment: @VGR its running the for each 1000 times in a while loop. it for sure is crossing passing. the for each is for sure honoring the synchronize, which im surprised about

Answer (score -1):

When two threads try to modify the same nonconcurent collection, the JVM may throw a concurentModificationException at runtime. In fact it can happen with a single thread. Take a look in the code below.

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
for(String text:list){
     list.remove(text);
}
```

To avoid this situation you can use the concurrent collections. You can use CopyOnWriteArraylist instead.

Comment: This is true, but it does not answer the question that was asked.

Comment: If you are trying to suggest tips, use the comments. Only answers should be posted as such